# Глюки очереди проверок

Tags: дефект, очередь-проверок

Не первый раз наблюдаю отметку на очереди "Голоса за повторное открытие" при отсутствии данных на обработку.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Где-то уже писали про несогласованность кэшей, привязанных к различным частям сайта.

Comment: Дам там вечная проблема с кешем O: